# Height change closes sidebar

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, responsive

I have a sidebar while displaying on mobile and entering the search input field, it closes once mobile keyboard is open and also if the height of the page is changed in browser inspection as shown in the following images:

[image]  [image]

this is the only code contains `innerHeight`

```
function fitContent() {
    var top = $(window).scrollTop() < 340 ? 270 - $(window).scrollTop() : 0;
    rightSide.css("top", top + "px");
    content.css("min-height", window.innerHeight - 130 + "px");
    var window_Width = window.innerWidth;
    if (window_Width < 1366) {
      closeRightSide();
    } else {
      openRightSide();
    }
}
```

and `fitContent` functions runs under `window.resize` and `document.ready`. Also that sidebar has open and close functions which toggle between two classes and changes the boolean value of an attribute.

```
function openRightSide() {
    body.removeClass("shrink");
    body.addClass("expand");
    rightSide.attr("data-expand", "true");
}
```

I noticed that `data-expand` attribute turns to false when the height is changed. and there is no additional code or css related to it.

#### The Question:

**How can I prevent height changes from closing the sidebar? What piece of code can I use?**

Comment: is your `closeRightSide()` is also calling some event on height or width resize?

Comment: @Rnayak no. it just do the opposite of the `openRightSide` function

Comment: can you share it on jsfiddle?
Else, try debuging on `content.css("min-height", window.innerHeight - 130 + "px");`
it might be causing some error as what happen if height after opening keyboard is less then 130px, then it will overwrite the property and will show error

Comment: @Rnayak I may try recreate something minimal as this is a part of a big project. nothing in code manipulate the height or even just use it. Can you help making a sort of a snippet to prevent that closing action? I don't know if this is relatable to keyboard only or what

Comment: is it a modal?
if not try using it as modal, It might solve your problem

Comment: @Rnayak Do you mean like bootstrap modal? if not please refer a link to an example